Passing arrays from child process to parent process using pipes
I am trying to send a large array which half of its values are calculated by the child process and the other half is calculated by the parent process. I would like the parent process to obtain the calculated values for half of the array from the child process and merge/join both arrays from both processes together so that I have one final array which is the product of the child and parent array calculations added together. I am trying to use the piping method only. My current code uses a "dummy" array which is the determined array calculations for the child process. This array is then passed into the parent process through piping which allows for the Test->iterations array results from the parent process to be added all together. The array is defined in a structure called Test which is in the format of:
typedef struct{
int *iterations
int height;
int width;
int start;
int end;
} Test;

Since this is a 2D array, the size of iterations is Test->width * Test->height * sizeof(int)). I am also sending the array using chunk read and write functions since it is a very large array.
My parallel program function (function where the two processes are spawned) follows the format of
int main(){
Test t;

t.height=1000;
t.width=1000;

if ((t->iterations = malloc(t->width * t->height * sizeof(int))) == 
NULL) {
    perror("Cannot allocate memory (iterations)");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

processes(Test *);

}

void processes(Test *){
int p2c[2], c2p[2];
int i,j,k;
int half;


int *dummy = malloc(Test->width*Test->height*sizeof(int));
    if(dummy==NULL){
        perror("Malloc Error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

for (i = 0; i < Test->height; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < Test->width; j++) {
        dummy[i * Test->width + j] = 0.0;
    }
}

    
half=Test->height >> 1;

pipe(p2c);
pipe(c2p);

if(fork()==0){
    
    Test->start=0;
    Test->end=half;

    Compute(Test);

    for(i=Test->start;i<Test->end;i++){
        for(j=0;j<Test->width;j++){

        dummy[i*Test->width+j]=Test->iterations[i*Test->width+j];
            
        }
    }
    
    chwrite(c2p[WRITE], (char*)dummy, Test->width * half * sizeof(int), 2048);
    
    printf("Sending Iterations\n");

    close(p2c[READ]);
    close(c2p[WRITE]);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    
}

else{

    

    Test->start=half;
    Test->end=Test->height;
    
    Compute(Test);
    sleep(1);

    chread(c2p[READ], (char*)dummy, Test->width * half * sizeof(int), 2048);
    
    printf("Reading Iterations\n");

    wait(NULL);

    
    for(i=0;i<Test->height;i++){
        for(j=0;j<Test->width;j++){
        Test->iterations[i*Test->width+j]=dummy[i*Test->width+j];
            
        }
    }

However, when i do this, the iterations array is full of zeros. What is the problem and how can i fix this?
My chunk read and write functions are as follows:
void chwrite(int fd, char *buf, int count, int chunksize){

int numChunks = (int)(count/chunksize);

int remsize = count-numChunks*chunksize; 

int i, j;

for(i=0,j=0; i<numChunks; j+=chunksize,i++){

    write(fd, &(buf[j]), chunksize);
    
}

write(fd, &(buf[j]),remsize);

}

void chread(int fd, char *buf, int count, int chunksize){

int numChunks = (int)(count/chunksize);
int remsize=count-numChunks*chunksize;

int i,j;

for(i=0,j=0; i<numChunks; j+=numChunks, i++){
    read(fd, &(buf[j]),chunksize);

}

read(fd, &(buf[j]) ,remsize);

}


"I am trying to send a large array which half of its values are calculated by the child process and the other half is calculated by the parent process" - It sounds like using threads instead of processes would be a lot more efficient. You then don't need to pass these large arrays through a pipe. You only need to synchronize the reads and writes to the array.

Yes threading would be much more efficient however I am required to do this algorithm by processes :(

What are chwrite() and chread()? Do you check return values of undelaying write() and read()? You closed write end of the pipe in child process then are trying to write to it.

Ok, please provide a [mre] so that we can compile and run it to observe the same thing you observe.

I added the chwrite() and chread() functions in the question. They are to send the iterations array in chunks rather than just write() as it exceeds the data limit of piping

@Lach We still can't compile it without making changes/additions to the code you've provided. That requires us to guess what you've actually done in order for us to be able to debug the program. Please provide a [mre].

Do not blindly assume that read and write will fully read or write the requested amount. Check the return value to see how much is actually read or written (or to see if there was an error).

@Lach always check return values of read()/write(). read() may return less bytes than requested.

Are p and Test the same? If not, do they contain the same values?

I cannot see Test->start or Test->end anywhere in the struct declaration.

In chread, should j+=numChunks be j+=chunksize?

@Lach You see what happens without a [mre]? People start guessing.

How did variable Test t; turn into a pointer variable called Test?

The chwrite and chread functions do not check for errors or incomplete writes or reads. Also, there is a bug in chread where j is being increased by numChunks instead of by chunksize:
for(i=0,j=0; i<numChunks; j+=numChunks, i++){
    read(fd, &(buf[j]),chunksize);

}

Here is a possible replacement for chread that checks for errors and allows incomplete reads. It returns the amount read if anything has been read, returns 0 if nothing has been read and either the amount to be read was 0 or an end-of-file condition was encountered, or -1 if nothing was read and an error was encountered:
int chread(int fd, char *buf, int count, int chunksize){
   int done = 0;
   int rc = count ? -1 : 0;
   while (done < count) {
       if (chunksize > done - count) {
           chunksize = done - count;
       }
       rc = read(fd, &buf[done], chunksize);
       if (rc <= 0) {
           break;
       }
       done += rc;
   }
   return done ? done : rc;
}

Here is a replacement chwrite function. It is similar to chread except that there is no check for an end-of-file condition. (An end-of-file condition doesn't make sense on write, and a properly functioning write call should not return 0 unless called with a count of 0.):
int chwrite(int fd, const char *buf, int count, int chunksize){
   int done = 0;
   int rc = count ? -1 : 0;
   while (done < count) {
       if (chunksize > done - count) {
           chunksize = done - count;
       }
       rc = write(fd, &buf[done], chunksize);
       if (rc < 0) {
           break;
       }
       done += rc;
   }
   return done ? done : rc;
}

There is also a problem in the parent process overwriting the second half of the test results with zeros here:
    for(i=0;i<Test->height;i++){
        for(j=0;j<Test->width;j++){
        Test->iterations[i*Test->width+j]=dummy[i*Test->width+j];
            
        }
    }

(Note: OP's incomplete code has a variable t of type Test so the the use of a pointer called Test is very probably incorrect and shouldn't even compile, but let's go with it for now. OP's incomplete code has other errors, such as the function call processes(Test *); and the function definition void processes(Test *){ … }.)
The outer for loop condition should be i<half or i<Test->start:
    for(i=0;i<Test->start;i++){
        for(j=0;j<Test->width;j++){
        Test->iterations[i*Test->width+j]=dummy[i*Test->width+j];
            
        }
    }

